# Vector: Argument list of class template: "std::vector is missing"

Tags: c++

I'm using the following guide http://rodrigo-silveira.com/opengl-tutorial-parsing-obj-file-blender/#.UTRmkvUudqI

because i'm trying to load an obj file in webgl.
In my RokkoParse.cpp file I use 'vector'.
But my compiler is saying that "std::vector is missing" I tried to search this error on the web but i could not fnid anything good.
Can someone help me where my issue is?

RokkoParses.h

```
    #pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

class RokkoParser
{
public:

public:
   static void objToTxt(const string aInFilename, 
                        const string aOutFilename, 
                        bool aVerbose = false);
   static std::vector explode(string aStr, char aDelim);
};
```

RokkoParser.cpp

```
    #include "StdAfx.h"
#include "RokkoParser.h"
#include <cstdio> // instead of <stdio.h>
// #include <conio.h> -- do not use
#include <cstring> // instead of <string.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


vector RokkoParser::explode(string aStr, char aDelim)
{
  vector res;
  string str = aStr.substr(0, aStr.find(aDelim));

  while(str.size() < aStr.size())
  {
    res.push_back(str);
    aStr = aStr.substr(aStr.find(aDelim) + 1);
    str = aStr.substr(0, aStr.find(aDelim));
  }

  res.push_back(str);

  return res;
}
```

In both files they say the same error

Thanks!

Comment: std::vector is not a type. It is a template to what you have to supply arguments to make it type.

Answer (score 12):

`vector` is a class *template*. When you declare a vector, you must specify what type the vector's elements shall have: "a vector *of what*"?

For instance:

```
std::vector<int> vi;         // This declares a vector of integers
std::vector<std::string> vs; // This declares a vector of strings
// ...
```

In your code, you use `std::vector` without any template argument. This is why the compiler complains.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you didn't give us the complete error message and it actually says "std::vector is missing a type argument" or something similar.

The reason for this is that `vector` is a class template, you have to tell it what kind of objects you want it to hold, e.g. `vector<int>` or `vector<string>`.